# NMOCK3 - Expects.One.Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nmock

I am new to Mocking and Unit Testing in general.  Please see the code below which I found online:

```
[Test]
        public void CanQueryViewUseAccountServiceToFundsTransfer()
        {
            _viewMock.Expects.One.Method(v => v.GetSourceAccount()).WillReturn("1234");
            _viewMock.Expects.One.GetProperty(v => v.TargetAccount).WillReturn("9876");
            _viewMock.Expects.One.GetProperty(v => v.TransferAmount).WillReturn(200.00m);
            _serviceMock.Expects.Exactly(1).Method(s => s.TransferFunds(null, null, 0m)).With("1234", "9876", 200.00m);
            _presenter.Transfer_Clicked();
            _mocks.VerifyAllExpectationsHaveBeenMet();
        }
```

I cannot find any documentation at all that explain what the following lines do:

```
_viewMock.Expects.One.Method //Is this saying it is expecting one and only one function to be called?
_viewMock.Expects.One.GetProperty
```

I have tried to find answers myself.  For example I looked here: http://nmock3.codeplex.com/documentation, but all I can find is FAQs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on the source code of [ExpectsOfT.cs](http://nmock3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MAIN/Source/NMock/Syntax/ExpectsOfT.cs):

```
public IMethodSyntax<T> One
{
    get
    {
        return Exactly(1);
    }
}
```

One might draw a conculsion that `.One` refers to **exactly one** expectation/call to the given method.

> I am new to Mocking and Unit Testing in general.

Any reason you are learning with NMock? As far [as I can see](http://nmock3.codeplex.com/documentation) it's not very popular and doesn't seem to be actively developed. There are libraries with far better documentation and community, for example [**Moq**](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) (*sample of more or less equivalent code*):

```
_viewMock.Setup(v => v.GetSourceAccount()).Returns("1234");
```

or [**FakeItEasy**](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy)

```
A.CallTo(() => _viewMock.GetSourceAccount()).Returns("1234");
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting moq and fakeiteasy. Do you have a preference between these two.

Comment: @w0051977: not really, although I like FakeItEasy syntax more (it reads more fluently).